# SSMS show last x records

Tags: sql-server

You can set the quantity of records that will be displayed, or remove the limit to show all records in the table.

Is it also possible to show the last x records?

If you have a very large table, all the records need to be loaded before you can go to the last records in the table.

I mean when you make a selection from the right click menu on a table name.

Not after the loading of all records or the use of the SQL query input form.

Comment: Just reverse the ODER BY

Comment: Hello Serg, thank you for your answer, I've added  some more information in my question.

Comment: _"If you have a very large table, all the records need to be loaded before you can go to the last records in the table."_ - **Nope** - that is not how an RDMBS works: if a query results in a full-table-scan then it means your DB was designed by someone incompetent. Please read-up on how query-execution-plans and indexes work.

Comment: You need to show us what you've tried

Comment: You have to write a query. You can't do this with a right-click on the table using out-of-the box SSMS functionality.

Comment: I right clicked on the table name and clicked on "Select All Rows" or with a limit "Select Top 200 Rows", So I'm looking for an option to "Select Last 200 Rows"

Comment: Hi StoneGiant, I realise that too, but can't understand why this is not possible with the right click menu, I think that's an option the MS developers over looked.

Comment: @Giancarlo _"but can't understand why this is not possible with the right click menu"_ - because SSMS is not a data-exploration tool, it's a server-administration tool. For Data Exploration, use Azure Data Explorer (which is bundled with SSMS).

Comment: Because Last means you actually have to specify *by what criteria*. I mean, sure, they could've implemented it but you could write the code yourself.

Comment: "last" is contextual, how would SSMS know what column(s) to use for sorting that would meet your definition of "last" on every table? Just use a simple query, or create a view e.g. `Select Top(200) from yourtable order by yourtimestampcolumn DESC`

Comment: You can also bind shortcut keys to a procedure call. One can implement a procedure that accepts table name, find out the PK and then takes TOP X rows ordered by PK desc